# Borel Measurable Set Related to Sections

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a Borel set and define
\begin{equation}
E^x=\{y\in\mathbb{R}\colon(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\}
\end{equation}
for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, where we identify $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}$. Given an interval $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ define
\begin{equation}
X_I=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\colon0<\lambda(I\cap E^x)<\lambda(I)\}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it necessarily true that $X_I$ is Borel measurable? If not, what further conditions can we impose to guarantee that $X_I$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: How do you know $\lambda(I \cap E^x)$ makes sense? That is, how do you know $E^x$ is measurable?

Comment: @mathworker21: If $E$ is Borel, then $E^x$ is Borel.  First show that if $E$ is open, then $E^x$ is (open and therefore) Borel; next show that the collection of all $E$ such that $E^x$ is Borel is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: @GEdgar that makes sense, but I'm conflicted. what if $E = N \times \{0\}$ for some non-measurable set $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$? Then $E$ has outer measure 0 and is thus measurable. Is my issue that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable and not Borel measurable?

Comment: @mathworker21: There is no mention of Lebesgue measurable sets at all, neither in the OP nor in my comment.  Both are for Borel sets.  (It is true that if $E$ is Lebesgue measurable, then there may exist $x$ such that $E^x$ is not Lebesgue measurable.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part of the statement of Fubini's theorem asserts that for any Borel measurable set $E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$, $$
x\mapsto \lambda(E^x)
$$ is a Borel measurable function. Note that
$$
E^x \cap I = \left(E \cap [\mathbb{R}^{n}\times I] \right)^x.
$$ Hence, it easily follows that $X_I$ is Borel measurable as a level set of a Borel measurable function.

It is more subtle if we consider a Lebesgue measurable $E$. We can show that
$$
x\mapsto \lambda(E^x)
$$ is defined for almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and it admits a measurable version. Thus, your set $X_I$ is Lebesgue measurable in this case.